# how to put user to login if he not log-in

Tags: php

i am working on login page but my problem is, when user type the url in browser it go to the home page even he not login. i want to redirect user in login page if he not login and go to home if he already login

this is my login.php

```
<form action='code.php' method='POST'>
<input name='login_input' type='text'>
<button name='login_btn' type='submit'>
</form>
```

this is my code.php

```
if(isset($_POST['login_btn'})){
    $input = $_POST['login_input'];

    if($input == "123")
    {
       $_SESSION['success'] = $input;
       header('Location: homepage.php');   
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: login.php');
    }
}
```

and this is my security.php

```
if (isset($_SESSION['success']) && $_SESSION['success'] == '')) {

    header('Location: login.php');
 }
```

in that code when i login it goes to homepage.php,  but if i write url to homepage.php it goes to the home page even he not login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ( ! isset($_SESSION['success']) && empty( $_SESSION['success'] ) )) {

    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include your security.php in the begining of the homepage.php file.

Note: add an exit(); after all your header('Location: xxxx.php'); to be sure the user don't access restricted area if the header don't work properly for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

in your homepage.php include your security.php

in your security.php

`if(!isset($_SESSION('success'))){
 header('Location: login.php');
}`

that means if $_SESSION('success') is not set redirect to login.php if authenticated proceed